# What is the theological justification behind chanting the holy names in Gaudiya Vaishnavism?

Tags: practice, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon, nama-japa, harinam-sankirtan

Gaudiya Vaishnavas chant the name of the Supreme Lord Sri Krishna and Rama. They call it Nama Yajna.

In some places, they have been doing continuously it for hundreds of years. For example, in Katwa (West Bengal), where Lord Chaitanya took sannyasa, chanting has been taking place for 500 years. It is supposed to continue for 1000 years!

ISKCON also does the same. In Prabhupada Bhajan Kutir (Mayapur), nonstop Harinam Sankirtan is going on.

Chanting is the most crucial spiritual process in that school. Why is so? In Hinduism, there are other spiritual processes like yajna, puja, meditation etc. Why among all these processes chanting is the supreme path in Gaudiya Vaishnavism?

By the way, this question is not about what is the right method of chanting ([Is there a time, place or method for chanting the holy name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7153/is-there-a-time-place-or-method-for-chanting-the-holy-name)). This is about the theological justification behind chanting.

Comment: Japa Yajna or Japa Yoga is mentioned as a superior path in many scriptures .. so nothing wrong if someone is following it --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9272/4732

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Superiority of Japa Yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9272/superiority-of-japa-yoga)

Comment: Japa and harinam sankirtan are two different things.

Comment: Nama Sankirtana is nothing but Nama Japa so not a different thing

Comment: harinam sankirtan is a congregational chanting. Japa is done in private. It is the repetition (not loudly) of a mantra, mostly connected to tantra.

Comment: Not necessary to do Japa in private .. it can be done loudly too (there are 3 modes of doing Japa) .. Nama Sankirtana is nothing but Nama Japa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, *harinama-sankirtana* is enjoined by the scriptures. Vishnu himself ratifies it.**

Once Nārada asked Lord Viṣhṇu where he does he actually resides. Thus, Lord Viṣhṇu replied:

> [Padma Purana: Uttara Khanda - 92.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365671.html)
>
> > Then the devotee, with a pleased mind and devoted, should go, taking with him
> > sandal, flowers, good tāmbūlas to the temple of Viṣṇu and Śiva. Then
> > having separately offered articles (and modes) of worship like water
> > for washing the feet, respectful oblation etc., and bowed again, he
> > should do auspicious things like singing. He should also honour the
> > good dancers having musical instruments made of bell-metal, lutes,
> > tabors etc., so also he should honour the singers with fragrant
> > flowers and tāmbūlas, since they are the forms of Viṣṇu. In the Kali
> > age penance, sacrifice, gifts made with devotion to the good lord of
> > the world, always give delight.
>
> O king, I (Nārada) asked, “O lord of gods,
> where do you live?”
>
> > **Viṣṇu, pleased with my devotion then spoke to me
> > thus:**
>
> नाहं वसामि वैकुण्ठे योगिनां हृदये न च ।
>  मद्भक्ता यत्र गायन्ति तत्र
> तिष्ठामि नारद ॥
>
> > **“I do not live in Vaikuṇṭha, nor in the heart of the yogins. O Nārada,
> > I stay there where my devotees sing (my praise).”**

---

Further, the Nārada-Pancaratra also considers the Name-chanting as the Supreme.

> ##### [*Forth Ratra, Chapter 3*](https://archive.org/details/NaradaPancaratraFull/Narada%20Pancaratra%20part%202/page/n265/mode/2up), Nārada-Pancaratra
>
> ksetresu vaisnavesv  etad aryavatte bhavisyati  nasti visnoh param
> satyarh  nasti-visnoh param padam
>
> > If these holy names are chanted in a holy place in the land  of
> > Aryavarta, they will award one increased benefit. Know for  certain
> > that there is no truth superior to Lord Visnu, and no  goal superior
> > to Him.
>
> Text 200
>
> nasti visnoh param jhanam  nasti mokso hy avaisnavah  nasti-visnoh
> paro-maniro  nasti-visnoh param tapah
>
> > There is no knowledge superior to the understanding of Lord  Visnu, no
> > liberation superior to association with Lord Visnu,  **no mantra
> > superior to the holy names of Lord Visnu, and no  penance superior to
> > surrender to Lord Visnu.**
>
> Text 201
>
> nasti visnoh param dhyanam  nasti mantro hy avaisnavah.  kin tasya
> bahubhir mantraih  kimjapair bahu-vistaraih
>
> > **There is no meditation superior to the remembrance of Lord  Visnu’s
> > transcendental name, form, and pastimes. There is no mantra greater
> > than the holy names of Lord Visnu. Considering this — what is the use
> > of chanting other mantras in relation to  Lord Visnu?**
>
> Text 202
>
> bajapeya-sahasraih kirn  bhaktir yasya janardane  sarva-tlrthamayo
> visnuh
> sarva-sastramayah prabhuh
>
> > **What is the need of performing thousands of *vajapeya* sacrifices if
> > one is engaged in the devotional service of Lord Visnu? Lord  Visnu is
> > the most sacred of all sacred places and the goal of all religious
> > performances.**
>
> Text 203
>
> sarva-kratumayo visnuh
> satyarh satyam vadamy aham  dbrahma-sdra-sarvasvarh  sarvam etan
> mayoditam
>
> > I am telling you the truth — Lord Visnu is the actual enjoyer of all
> > sacrifices. I have thus revealed to you the essence of everything
> > within the universe

And hence, we have the theological justification behind chanting (*hari-nama-samkirtanam*).

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add what Lord Chaitanya said.

> সব-লোক-কর্ণ-গর্ত্ত কুন্ড-পরিসর।
> জিহবা-স্রুব, ধ্বনি-রস ঘৃত মনোহর।।

> sab lok karna garta kunda parisar|
> jihva srub dhwani rasa ghrita manohar||

> "**The living entities' ears are sacrificial pit. The tongue is the sacrificial ladle. The sound of Lord Krishna's glories is the sacrificial offering (ghee)**." -*Caitanya-Mangala, Madhya-khanda, Chapter 9, Song 21, verse 81*.

Caitanya Mangala is one of the standard biographies of Lord Chaitanya. It was written around 16th Century by Locana Dasa Thakur.

So what Lord Caitanya meant is that chanting the holy names (Harinam Sankirtan) is similar to performing a Vedic sacrifice. This metaphor is quite interesting.